# Java synchronized method not working

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm trying to figure out what I am doig wrong right here. My plan is to increment a static variable but lock it so only one thread at a time can do that. Here's my code:
Test.java

```
    public class Test implements Runnable {

    private static int NUM=0;
    private static int CURRENT_ID = 0;

    private final int id = Test.CURRENT_ID++;

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        this.raise();
    }

    private synchronized void raise() {
        for( int i=0 ; i<5 ; ++i ) {
            ++Test.NUM;
            System.out.println("["+ this.id +"] " + Test.NUM);
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for( int i=0 ; i<3 ; ++i ) {
            ex.execute(new Test());
        }
        ex.shutdown();
    }
}
```

I expect output like from thread 0 increasing, then 1, 2 after that and so on. Instead they're mixed, that means all of them are using variable `Test.NUM` at the same time, what is totally wrong.

Comment: Do you know what `synchronized` does?

Comment: You are creating separate instances of the Test class. This means each object has its raise method synchronised, but that doesn't help you, as you want to synchronise on something that is shared between all those instances.